# CiviDiscount - Manual Event Registration Issue with Automatic Discount

Tags: civievent, registration, cividiscount

I am using cividiscount - I am an admin and also a member - I created a discount that provides an automatic 10% for members, which has been great - however, when I go to manually register an event participant - it automatically includes my member 10% discount for their registration - any way to avoid this?

Comment: When you manually enter a participant are you entering them through the registration form on your website or the back end 'add a participant'? Also, what version of CiviCRM are you using and which CMS.

Comment: @KilakwaBT Sorry I forgot to include it - Wordpress 4.8 and CiviCRM 4.7.19. I am using the CiviCRM back end, not via front facing website.